# Does anyone have the latest aws mobile hub developer guide that includes dynamodb as well?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-mobilehub

I wanted to setup a backend for my mobile app. I came across the AWS mobile hub which is quite appealing. In the latest update they have included the NoSQL DynamoDB as well but I cannot find the documentation for this anywhere. The developer guide for AWS mobile hub does not include DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Mobile Hub Developer Guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/mobile-hub/